# VLC Screen saver issue

Tags: vlc-media-player, screensaver

I uncheck disable screensaver in vlc however windows screen saver turns off display while I'm watching video. When disable screensaver is checked in vlc windows screensaver will not turn off display at all which is an issue. I want windows screensaver to work so that there is more security on my computer. How can I prevent windows screensaver from interrupting vlc video without checking disable screensaver?

Answer (score 2):

Since this problem is related to the operating system of any computer, this solution works for any other video player which has the same problem on screensavers.

How to disable VLC player's Screensaver for good!

While playing or after played a video on VLC, the Windows screensaver will come on (activate).

The settings option within the VLC won't work to disable it. See the path:

VLC -Tools - Preferences Go to left bottom column at Show settings and activate All button. Navigate down to Video section. Mark the option "Disable screensaver" All that won't disable the screensaver because VLC is related to your Windows settings for screensaver.

Therefore, go to Desktop, right-click, and go to Screensaver options. In Windows Vista is: right-click on Desktop - Personalize - Screen Saver.

Look at "Wait" value. If it says 10 minutes, VLC will activate the screensaver after 10 minutes of idle, EVEN THOUGH your windows screensaver is deactivated. If it say 1 minute, VLC will do it after 1 minute, and so on.

To fix all this problem, is to cheat: change the value to a very high one, like 480 minutes.

Change the value activating the screen saver and deactivating it just like i did before.

From now on, VLC won't bother you at all

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble recently. My screen kept turning off while watching a show. I checked and unchecked the screensaver option in VLC settings to no avail. Then I discovered something.

Screensaver settings is different from screen turning off settings on my windows 10 laptop. At the time of this writing, **screen off** settings are adjusted in "**Power & Sleep**" settings. Just type *screen off* in the search bar. There are 2 (Plugged in, Battery Power) See screenshot included below.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsFGC.jpg):

This allows me to plug in my laptop at a friends house and watch a show without having to keep touching the screen to keep it on. And still have my screensaver work.

I still use security measures WIN+L to log out or close the laptop any time I walk away from it.
There are other measures you can take that are beyond the scope of your question. But this should answer this question for anyone who comes here with the same trouble.